# Type traits `is_noexcept`, `add_noexcept`, and `remove_noexcept`?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, noexcept, c++23

Motivation: In the implementation of [P0288](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0288r9.html#Specification) `std::move_only_function`, I'd like to write a non-allocating special case for conversion from `move_only_function<int() noexcept>` to `move_only_function<int()>`:

```
move_only_function<int() noexcept> f = []() noexcept { return 42; };
move_only_function<int()> g = std::move(f);  // should just copy the bits
```

I want to write, like,

```
if constexpr (is_noexcept_version_of<HisSignature, MySignature>::value) { ... }
```

I wanted to implement that type trait like this:

```
template<class, class>
struct is_noexcept_version_of : std::false_type {};

template<class Tp>
struct is_noexcept_version_of<Tp noexcept, Tp> : std::true_type {};
```

but no vendor accepts that; they all think `Tp noexcept` is a syntax error.

Question: How would you write this kind of type-trait without a combinatorial explosion of partial specializations, i.e. without exhaustively going through all the possible combinations of `&`, `&&`, `const`, etc.? Is it possible to write simple closed-form type traits for `is_noexcept_v<T>`, `add_noexcept_t<T>` and `remove_noexcept_t<T>`?

Comment: "*should just copy the bits*" Um... how exactly would that work?

Comment: @NicolBolas: FYI, it ends up working [like this](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/llvm-project/commit/a7efa30bf9481999e5fff6379f68d39506a60289). And it turned out that I didn't even need this type-trait; a stronger version of user17732522's argument proves that _in any case where the implicit conversion is permitted_, we don't need any further test (and if it's _not_ permitted then we never get into the converting ctor's body anyway). (Future readers take note: this is all `move_only_function` trivia unrelated to the actual type-trait question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from qualification conversions, the only possible implicit conversions between pointer-to-function types are the ones that remove `noexcept` and similarly for pointers-to-member-functions (except for base-to-derived conversion), so I think the following should work

```
struct C {};

template<class A, class B>
struct is_noexcept_version_of : std::bool_constant<
    requires {
       requires std::is_convertible_v<A C::*, B C::*>;
       requires std::is_function_v<A>;
       requires !std::is_same_v<A, B>;
    }> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can reduce the length of the combinatorial mess by combining stuff.

```
template<class F>
struct function_info;

template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct function_info<R (T::*)(Args...) const&&>:
  function_helper< R(Args...), class_t<T>, const_v, rvalue_v >
{};
// ^^^^^ combinatorial explosion here ^^^^^
// You have to decompose the type into its independent dimensions, so
// you get 12 (24 if you want to support both methods and functions
// transparently). 

template<class Sig, class T, auto constness, auto refness, auto exceptness >
struct function_helper:
  base_properties<Sig, T, constness, refness, exceptness>
  derived_properties<Sig, T, constness, refness, exceptness>
{};
template<class Sig, class T, auto constness, auto refness, auto exceptness >
using function_helper_t = typename function_helper<Sig, T, consteness, refness, exceptness>::type;


template<class Sig, class T, auto constness, auto refness, auto exceptness>
struct derived_properties {
  using without_const = function_helper_t<Sig, T, no_const_v, refness, exceptness >;
  using with_const = function_helper_t<Sig, T, const_v, refness, exceptness >;
  // ... add/remove each property here.  An add/remove for each dimension.
  // This is the spot that this technique saves on lines
};

template<class Sig, class T, auto constness, auto refness, exceptness >
struct func_type;
// combinatorial explosion here:
template<class R, class...Args, class T>
struct func_type<R(Args...), T, const_v, rvalue_v, noexcept_v> {
  using type = R(T::*) const&& noexcept;
};
// ^^^^^ You have to rebuild the type from the dimensional values, which
// means you get 2 * 3 * 2 = 12 different copy-pastas here ^^^

template<class Sig, class T, auto constness, auto refness, auto exceptness >
struct base_properties:
  func_type<Sig, T, constness, refness, exceptness >
{
  using sig_t = Sig;
  using class_t = T;
  constexpr auto const_v = constness;
  constexpr auto ref_v = refness;
  constexpr auto except_v = exceptness;
};
```

this at least removes one layer in the combinatorial explosion; namely, assuming you want to do the same thing with a bunch of other types (noexcept, const, reference ness, etc).

We decompose the type in one spot, and we recompose it in another, and we can reuse those decompositions/recompositions.